# C++ Loops For Even and Odd Numbers

Tags: c++

Write a program that asks the user for non-negative integers X and Y. Using a loop, alternate between adding and multiplying integers starting at X and finishing at Y. If the number is even, add it to the total. If the number is odd, multiply it. For example, if X=5 and Y=10, your program should calculate ((5+6)*7+8)*9+10=775. If X=2 and Y = 5, calculate (2*3+4)*5=50.

I know how to split the even and odd number, but I have no idea how to put it together.

Comment: This is a one-liner using `std::accumulate`.  So are you ready to see this solution and understand (using your own research) what `accumulate` does?

Comment: `if (number % 2 == 0) { /* it's even */ } else { /* it's odd */ }`

Answer (score 2):

Proper explanations :
First step is checking that input is correct (y is greater than x and both values are positive).

Then you initialize the variable that you'll use for returning the result to `x` (because we always start from `x` according to the examples you gave us) : `int res = x;`.

The you have the looping : Since we start from `x`, just loop from `x+1` to `y` (included, again accordingly with the examples you gave us) : `for(int i = x+1 ; i <= y; i+=1)`

In this loop you have the current value, if this current value is even, add it to the result variable (`res += i;`), else (it is odd) you multiply the result by the current value (`res *= i`).

After the loop you can return the result variable and the job is done.

/!\SPOILER : complete code below

Here is the complete code

```
   int func(int x, int y){
      if(y>x && x>0){
        int res = x;
        for(int i = x+1 ; i <= y ; i+=1){
          if(i%2==0)
            res += i;
          else
            res *= i;
        }
        return res;
      }
      return -1;
    }
```

I just added the fact that it returns -1 if the input isn't "valid".

Comment: indeed, gonna correct that

Comment: are you sure it is a good practice to give full code in a question which is clearly an assignment?

Comment: Indeed, added explanations and spoiler (just in case Emendator would still want to look at the "finished product").

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are looping though `X` to `Y`and `i` is the iterator / current number in your loop and `tot` is the total number that you will output, inside your loop,
when `i` is even:

```
tot += i;
```

and when `i` is odd:

```
tot *= i;
```

You also have to choose the appropriate starting value for `tot`.

I would post the full code but it seems this is an assignment.

Answer (score 0):

First, check whether y is greater than X or not. If greater, run a loop starting at X and ending at Y. Take a variable which stores the total. If the loop variable is even add the value to the total variable and if the loop variable is odd multiply the value with the value of total variable.

```
int total=0;
if(y>x)
{
   for(int i=x;i<=y;i++)
   {
       if(i%2==0)       //if even
       {
           total += i;
       }
       else         //if odd
       {
           total *= i;  
       }
  }
}
cout<<total;
```